# NuGet не скачивает нужные мне расширения, ругается на разрыв соединения удаленного хоста

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Я начинающий программист и очень мало понимаю в этом деле. Я захотел установить графическую библиотеку OpenTK на VisualStudio(пишу на C#) и столкнулся со следующей проблемой. NuGet отказывается находить что-то и уж тем более докачивать в мой проект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В сумме я потратил на эту проблему уже 8 часов и никак не могу решить. Я модифицировал NuGet.Config в AppData, удалял его, ставил настройки NuGet в самой студии, но и это не помогало. Сторонние программы мешать не должны, я пробовал их все закрывать и запускать так. Доступ к https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json имеется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я залазил в regedit и нашел там вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю плохо ли то, что там нету TSL и может ли это быть связано, но я прошу у вас помощи. Пожалуйста, помогите. Я уже с ума схожу, руки опускаются и хочется на все забить.

Comment: Проблема только с OpenTK? Другие библиотеки ставятся? Попробуйте что-нибудь популярное: Entity Framework, Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Другие библиотеки тоже не ставятся, я пробовал скачать на другом компьютере и перекинуть dll в папку моего проекта, но так тоже не выходит

Comment: версия операционной системы какая? 7? сервис-пак какой? поддержка TLS 1.2 присутствует? Обновите винду и все заработает. Исходя из того что я вижу, операционная система не поддерживает TLS 1.2, поэтому соединение с NuGet не может быть установлено.

Comment: седьмой виндоус, сервис пак 1, про поддержку TSL уверенно сказать не могу. Похоже, и правда придется обновлять. Спасибо большое за помощь и оказанное внимание!